# Is it safe to store WCF client proxy in ThreadLocal<ICommunicationObject>

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Scenario:
A Windows Service would spawn a Task (say T1) for each file that arrives in a Network File share.
The File is then divided into Batches and these batches are send on to a Java WebService(SOAP) by spawning further tasks, Say a1, b1, c1....
Currently we are storing the WCF client proxy in 
    ThreadLocal
of tasks a1, b1, c1....
That is we are recreating the proxy for individual threads to increase the reliability and closing/aborting it once the call is done.

Can you please suggest any alternative design that can avoid the proxy creation cost or usage of thread local storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the proxy is thread safe, can you use one proxy for all your communication?

If the proxy is not-thread safe, you could maintain a pool of proxies. Tasks a1, b1, and c1 will checkout a proxy from the pool and then check the proxy back in when it has finished. The typical pooling problems will occur here, such as what to do if there is no free proxy when one is needed (Make one? "Wait" until one is ready? Should this new proxy be returned to the pool or discarded?) or what to do if a proxy enters a persistent error state.